# Missing text in PDF when using CGPDFContextCreateWithURL

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, core-graphics

I'm trying to create a simple pdf with some header text. I'm using CGPDFContextCreateWithURL to create the document. For some reason, no text is appearing, though I can get other drawing objects to appear.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

 drawSuperPDF("test4.pdf")
 showPDFFile()

 }
```

My drawSuperPDF() function

```
func drawSuperPDF(filename: String) {

let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let pdfFileName = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
let fullPath = pdfFileName.path!

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)


var mediaBox:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792)


let myPDFContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, &mediaBox, nil)

CGPDFContextBeginPage(myPDFContext, nil)
drawHeaders()



CGPDFContextEndPage(myPDFContext)


}
```

My drawHeaders() and drawHeaderText() functions

```
func drawHeaders() {


drawHeaderText(CGPoint(x: 30, y:  10), headerText: "Hello World:", underline: true)


drawHeaderText(CGPoint(x: 30, y: 25), headerText: "Hello World:", underline: true)


drawHeaderText(CGPoint(x: 30, y: 40), headerText: "Hello World:", underline: true)


drawHeaderText(CGPoint(x: 30, y: 70), headerText: "Hello World:", underline: true)




   }

func drawHeaderText(point: CGPoint, headerText: String, underline: Bool) {

let drawingPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y)

if underline {


    var multipleAttributes = [String : NSObject]()
      multipleAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] =     UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)
    multipleAttributes[NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] = NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue


    headerText.drawAtPoint(drawingPoint,
        withAttributes: multipleAttributes)


} else {

    let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    headerText.drawAtPoint(drawingPoint,
        withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])}

 }
```

And finally, my showPDFFile()

```
func showPDFFile() {

let fileName = "test4.pdf"
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let pdfFileName = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
let fullPath = pdfFileName.path!
let webView : UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
let url : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)
let request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

webView.scalesPageToFit = true
webView.loadRequest(request)

self.view.addSubview(webView)


}
```

Comment: Hi again :) You don't show the simple graphics calls that work, but I'm willing to bet they take a graphic context as a parameter... Your "drawAtPoint" function does not take a graphics context, so it likely doesn't know you want to draw in your PDF file. Have a look at "UIGraphicsPushContext"; call that before your text calls and see if that improves things :)

Comment: I just get a screen with no pdf when I try UIGraphicsPushContext. I also altered the functions to pass the context to the functions but no luck :(